# Getting hardware (Presenter) to work that only comes with windows driver

Tags: drivers, wine, hardware

Sorry for the bad title, couldnt think of a better one

Here is the situation: A while ago (when I had a notebook where I was unable to get any linux to run properly) I bought this piece of hardware [https://www.amazon.com/Samsung-PRESENTER-DONGLE-CY-PTR01PD-EN/dp/B00LBSBUYU](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00LBSBUYU) which comes with a piece of control software but only for windows.

The buttons work fine in my ubuntu, so the signal works. I would however also like the pointer functionality. Is there a way to get this to work? I (maybe naively) tried to run the installation software under wine. Which does something and gets the software running but it crashes and never really works.

Comment: Do you expect the mentioned hardware to act as a mouse? It's not really clear in your question what exactly you expect to happen.

Comment: @ElderGeek yes. thats the functionality that is not working right now (also it changes your mouse pointer symbol, but I can get around this)

Comment: If you run `xev` and use the pointer do you get any output?

Comment: @ElderGeek no that button does not seem to trigger anything

Comment: At this point all I can recommend is contacting the manufacturer and requesting  assistance in getting it working under Linux. Samsung Groups customer service number is 1 (800) 726-7864